# Finding the supremum of the set $\{\frac{n^2}{2^n}: n\in \Bbb N\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem:

> The supremum of the set $\{\frac{n^2}{2^n}: n\in \Bbb N\}$ is :
>
> 1.$\frac98\,\,$
>
> 2.$\,1\,\,$
>
> 3.$\,0\,\,$
>
> 4.does not exist

I need to determine which of the aforementioned options is correct?

The set is given by $\,\{\frac12,1,\frac98,1,\frac{25}{32},\frac{36}{64},\ldots\}$. So, for larger values of $n$ the $\frac{n^2}{2^n} \to 0$. So ,looking at the first few numbers,I think option 1 is the right choice. But, I am not sure how to pick up the supremum.

Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show by induction that $2^n \geq n^2$ for $n \geq 4$. It then follows that $\frac{9}{8}$ is the supremum, as for $n \geq 4$ all entries in the set are $\frac{n^2}{2^n}\leq\frac{2^n}{2^n}=1<\frac{9}{8}$.

Comment: Except that when $n=3$, you get $9/8>1$, so wouldn't that be the supremum?

Comment: @ChristopherToni yes, sorry.